# Data being inserted into wrong column on SQLITE3

Tags: swift, sqlite

I'm trying to insert data from user input into an SQLite database that I have set up. Here is the code that I have currently written:

```
var stmt: OpaquePointer?
let queryString = "INSERT INTO entries (id, name, email, avatar) VALUES (NULL,?,?,?)"

if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, queryString, -1, &stmt, nil) == SQLITE_OK){
        sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, strName, -1, nil)
        sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 2, strEmail, -1, nil)
        sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 3, "batman", -1, nil)
    }

else{
        let errMsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
        print("error preparing insert: \(errMsg)")
        return
}
```

strName and strEmail are being pulled from text fields. When I go to query this data in another view, for some reason "batman" has been inserted into the second column instead of the user input. This is the select query:

```
let queryString = "SELECT * FROM entries"
var stmt: OpaquePointer?

if sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, queryString, -1, &stmt, nil) != SQLITE_OK{
        let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
        print("error preparing select: \(errmsg)")
        return
}

while(sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_ROW){
        let id = sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 0)
        let name = String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 1))
        let email = String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 2))

        userList.append(User(id: Int(id), name: String(describing: name), email: String(describing: email)))
        print (id);
        print (name);
        print (email);
}
```

What I would expect to see from the output is:

1. 1
2. user name
3. user email

What I instead see:

1. 1
2. batman
3. user email

Am I doing something wrong with my insert statement?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the answer:

There was an issue with the `sqlite3_bind_text` that was causing the improper data to be inserted into the wrong rows.

Changed the bind statements from:

```
sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, strName, -1, nil)
sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 2, strEmail, -1, nil)
sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 3, "batman", -1, nil)
```

to:

```
sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, strName, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT)
sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 2, strEmail, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT)
sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 3, "batman", -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT)
```

with `SQLITE_TRANSIENT` defined as:

```
let SQLITE_TRANSIENT = unsafeBitCast(OpaquePointer(bitPattern: -1), to: sqlite3_destructor_type.self)
```

The data now returns properly when queried.